# Show $[0,1]$ less altered cantor set is dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F$ be the subset of $[0,1]$ constructed in the same manner as the Cantor ternary set except that each of the intervals removed at the nth step has length $\alpha 3^{-m}$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Show that $F$ is closed, $[0,1] \setminus F$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and $m(F) = 1 - \alpha$. Also, use $F$ to construct an open set that has a boundary of positive measure. Where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: $[0,1]\setminus F$ dense: Look at the centers of the intervals removed to build $F$. $m(F)=1-\alpha$: Compute $1-\sum_m \alpha 3^{-m}$. The last part: Prove that the boundary of $F$ is $F$.

Comment: @orole Well, what *are* the centres if we build $F$ the *same manner* as the Cantor set? This may depend on the precise description of the latter. For example, I might construct the Cantor set by removing all open intervals of length $3^{-m}$ centered around numbers $x$ with ternary expansion startiing in $m-1$ digits $\in\{0,2\}$ followed by $1$'s only. If I do *the same* except for shorter interval lengths, the result will not have dense complement.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Quoting "the same manner as the Canter ternary set except [for the size]".

Comment: Based on my typo, from now on I will call the Cantor ternary set with the portmanteau Canternary set.